# Distinguish between Remote and Remote Overseas on SO Jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

There are *a lot* of job ads on SO Jobs that are marked as remote, but when you read the requirements you see they are US only. My suggestion is to distinguish between jobs which are remote, but restricted to a certain country ("remote"), and those which you can work from other countries as well ("remote overseas").

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow isn't a community for only the US.

I suspect that using ***Remote Overseas*** will only add to the confusion. The US is ***overseas*** for a lot of people who are not in the US (e.g. Europe or Asia).

If you want to add something, it is probably better to add a continent or country name. E.g.: ***Remote Europe***.

However, as the comments below this answer also show, adding lables isn''t necessarily an improvement. In my opinion it is better to leave it to ***Remote***.

Comment: What I think the OP wants is for remote jobs to be treated like regional jobs if they have a residency requirement, e.g. to be filtered out if you search remote jobs from a location that is not the required country. That *does* make a lot of sense if "remote but xyz only" jobs are running rampant.

Comment: Isn't **Remote Europe** just as confusing? Does that mean I can only remote in in Europe or the company is just base in Europe?

Comment: @George that's why I said *"If you want to add something ..."*; imo it is just better to keep it at just *"Remote"*; see also the update

Comment: @Pekka웃 is right. I'm currently searching for remote jobs, however I lose a lot of time with these US-only ads. There are *a lot* of them, seriously. Some of them have even been recently edited with warnings on top written in bold like "YOU HAVE TO BE A US RESIDENT", so I guess I'm not the only one confused. 

So "overseas" would be an attribute of the ad, just like remote, which shows that the person can work remotely from another country.

Or maybe the other way around? "Remote (US Only)" or "Remote regional".

Comment: @andre_ss6 My main point is that using *"Overseas"* might add to the confusion. Using *"Remote (US Only)"* or *"Remote regional"* as you proposed is very similar to what I prosed in my answer. So, I can only agree with that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think we agree on the interpretation, but we just expressed it differently ;-) See also my previous comment.